# Excel - How to navigate through the columns and find desired cell?

Tags: excel

Can I get the value from my annotated image

[image]

without macro? If not, how would such a macro look like?

I need to automatically calculate a value in F13 which depends on SOME value from column G. This SOME value is found by indicator from column A. This indicator is the value "TL".

In my example in simple words:

To calculate value in F13

```
- go left to first column
- go up until value TL
- go right to column G
```

Comment: I cannot understand what you are really asking. F13 is 0.30€ in your example  so it is not the content of the cell G11.

Comment: F13 is calculated with the help of a factor, this factor is G11. The factor - in this case G11 - is found by value "TL".

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
=vlookup("TL",A2:G10,7,0)
```

But set the range in a accordingly, you may need $A$2:$G$10... edited array...

So, this will look at A the contents of cell A11 and drag down for A12 etc :

```
=vlookup(A11,A$11:G17,7,0)
```

So, an example:
[image]

Comment: There are many such entries in this sheet. So to set the range is not good. It would shift the work of manual entering just from one column to the next.

Comment: This is not working but maybe something similar to `=vlookup("TL",ADDRESS(ROW();1):A1,7,0)`? A reversed array, to search from bottom up.